# Mysql get the amount of products

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I have the following two tables

```
# vendor table
vendor_id     host
   1       192.168.0.2
   1       192.168.0.4
   1       192.168.0.6
   2       192.168.1.21
   2       192.168.1.23
   2       192.168.1.25
   2       192.168.1.27

# information table
    host        name
 192.168.0.2     bar
 192.168.0.4     bar1
```

What I need at the end is the following result set

```
vendor_id amount_live amount_total
    1         2            3
    2         0            4
```

The column amount_live is the amount of entries per vendor in the information table and the column amount_total is the amount of hosts in the vendor table per vendor.

Can some of the experts please tell me the mysql select statement to get the desired result set. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `count` and an `outer join`:

```
select v.vendor_id, 
   count(i.host) amount_live,
   count(*) amount_total
from vendor v
    left join information i on v.host = i.host
group by v.vendor_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/362f8/4)

Comment: count already counts non-null values, so you could just use `COUNT(i.host)`

Comment: @fthiella -- not sure what I was thinking (guess I need some coffee)!  Thanks, updated the answer ...

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. The only problem I'm having now is that the vendor table has over 20 million entries and the information table over 500'000 rows. So there is a performance problem I'm facing right now...if you guys have any trick would be awesome!
Running the query right now and it takes minutes...

Comment: @Laoneo -- np, glad it helped.  My guess is you don't have the appropriate indices in place.  Make sure you index the host fields in both tables.  Best regards.